How to narrow variable to subset of type argument union?
Given this simplified example:
type OnlyBlue<T> = T extends 'blue' ? 'blue' : null

function parseBlue<Color extends 'red' | 'green' | 'blue'>(input: Color): OnlyBlue<Color> {
  if (input === 'blue') {
    const output = input
    return output
  }

  return null
}

Why am I getting type errors in the return statements?

Hovering on return output shows this error:


Hovering on return null shows this error:



For some reason, input is not being narrowed to blue inside of the condition. Does anyone know why?
This is what TS shows me the type of output is:

I was expecting it to be just 'blue'
How do I get it to narrow?
Typescript 5.5.2

TS before 5.8 doesn't do control flow on generic types, see ms/TS#33912. This will change in TS5.8, and you can refactor your code to this version and it will narrow as expected. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

I would suggest to make a function factory so you could create any color parser and use function overrides with a type guard:
Playground
type Color = 'red' | 'green' | 'blue';

function makeColorParser<C extends Color>(color: C) {
  const isColor = (input: Color, color: Color): input is C => input === color;
  return parse;
  
  function parse<I extends C>(input: I): I;
  function parse<I extends Color>(input: I): null;
  function parse<I extends Color>(input: I): null | C{
    return isColor(input, color) ? input : null;
  }
}

const parseBlue = makeColorParser('blue');

const blue = parseBlue('blue'); // blue
const red = parseBlue('red'); // null
const some = parseBlue('yellow'); // error, no yellow in Colors

